# unordered_map c++ error

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I write this code:

On running, an error occurs in the line

```
cout<<it2->first;
```

> Unhandled exception at 0x00411edd in test3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004."

I have Visual Studio Express 2008 and Boost 1_47_0;

This is my full code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::unordered_map<int,int > MAP;
        MAP map2;
        boost::unordered_map<int,int>::iterator it2;

void gen_random(char *s  ,char *p,int*  r,const int len);
void inline insert2(int i_key,int i_value);
void print();
//-----------main------------------------------------
void main()
{   
    char* s_key=new char[8];
    char* s_value=new char[8];
    int i_value=0, size_random=8;
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        gen_random(s_key,s_value,&i_value,size_random);
         insert2(i_value,i_value);
    }

        print();
    int a;
    std::cin>>a;
}
//-------------end main--------------------------------

//--------my function ---------------------------
//-------random--------------
void gen_random(char* s,char* p,int *r, const int len) {


    static const char alphanum[] =
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
     (*r)=rand();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
         p[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }

    s[len] = 0;
    p[len] = 0;
}
//-----end random------------

    void inline insert2(int i_key,int i_value)
    {
        map2.insert(MAP::value_type(i_key,i_value));        
    }
    void print()
    {

    for(it2=map2.begin();it2 != map2.end();++it2 );
     {


         cout<<it2->first; 

     }

    }
//--------end function---------------------------
```

Comment: `s[len] = 0;` equals `s[8] = 0;`, and `s` is declared as 8-sized but you try to access the 9th element. Also, you could use the following iterator declaration : `MAP::const_iterator it2;`

Comment: This is awkwardly written, non-standard (`void main()` is not allowed in a C++ program), and in general difficult to read.  Could you try to condense this down into a smaller program that still fails?  Can VS 2008 Express tell you which line this is on?

Comment: Beginner's C++ Tip: "If you're using pointers, You're Doing It Wrong."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
for(it2=map2.begin();it2 != map2.end();++it2 );
```

Should not end in a semicolon.  The loop runs, but does not go into the block of code following it.  When the loop completes, `it2` is equal to `map2.end()` which is why you get an access violation when you try to use it.

This problem could have been avoided if you used a smaller scoped variable.  For example, this would get you a compiler error (assuming `it2` was no longer a global):

```
for(boost::unordered_map<int,int>::iterator it2 = map2.begin(); it2 != map2.end(); ++it2);
{
    cout<<it2->first;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> s[len] = 0;
>   p[len] = 0;

You are trying to assign values to `s[8]` and `p[8]` which are outside the array bounds. They are declared as `char[8]` so they can only be indexed from `0` to `7`.

Comment: @vahid: That is some information that you want to include in the original question. You are nevertheless causing undefined behavior, which could be the actual source of your problem. Though I doubt it, triggering undefined behavior makes the entire program be undefined. So start by fixing those invalid memory accesses.